# gtest, undefined reference to 'testing::Test::~Test()', testing::Test::Test()

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

i installed the gtest using `apt-get install libgtest-dev`

and i am trying to check if that is working or not.

so i make simple code for testing in eclipse.

but there are error,

> undefined reference to 'testing::Test::~Test()'
>   undefined reference
>   to 'testing::Test::Test()'

conversely if i change the inheritance at the ATest class as protected the error disappear but

the other error occur

> testing::Test is inaccessible base of 'ATest_AAA_Test'

what is wrong ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class A{
public:
    int a;
    A(int a){this->a = a;}
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    int getA(){return a;}
    void setA(int a){this->a = a;}
};

class ATest : public ::testing::Test{
public:
    virtual void SetUp(){
        a1 = A(1);
        a2 = A(2);
        a3 = A(3);
    }
    virtual void TearDwon(){}
    A a1;
    A a2;
    A a3;
};

TEST_F(ATest, AAA){
    EXPECT_EQ(1, a1.getA());
    EXPECT_EQ(2, a2.getA());
    EXPECT_EQ(3, a3.getA());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing `libgtest-dev` does not install any of the gtest binaries.
It simply installs the googletest source package on your system - headers
under `/usr/include/gtest` and source files under `/usr/src/gtest`,
where you could proceed to build it with `cmake` or GNU autotools
if you want.

There is no binary package for googletest in ubuntu/debian software channels
(or elsewhere that I know of). The normal practice is to
[download the source archive](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/downloads/list),
extract it and use binaries built by yourself. The `README` in the
source package gives guidance on building and using the library.

There is normally no purpose in performing a system install of
the source package, as you have done.

The linkage error you have encountered:

```
undefined reference to 'testing::Test::~Test()
```

has nothing to do with your code: it occurs because you are not
linking `libgtest`, and you cannot link it because it is not installed
by `libgtest-dev` and you have not built it yourself.

This linkage error disappears when you change the code in a way
that introduces a compilation error, because if compilation fails
then linkage does not happen.

Comment: Thank you, you was correct, but after building the src code of the gtest(i followed this [link](http://www.thebigblob.com/tag/libgtest-dev/)), the other error still happens. "make: *** [test] error 1"(test is the project name), of course i have added -lgtest flag.

Comment: sorry it work as i add -lpthread, originally -pthread is needed for gtest ?

Comment: When you build gtest you can configure it without pthread support:
`./configure --with-pthreads=no`. Or you can can pass the
preprocessor flag '-DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=0` when you make it:
`CPPFLAGS=-DGTEST_HAS_PTHREAD=0 make`. Then you won't need to link
the `pthread` library if your unit-tests don't need it.

Answer (score 12):

I know this sounds obvious but my psychic debugging skills tell me you forgot to add `-lgtest` *after* your object file name when you linked your final binary.

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to add `target_link_libraries(NodeTest ${GTEST_BOTH_LIBRARIES})`

Comment: In case you missed it: it's important that -lgtest comes AFTER your object file name